# WCF Integration Facility throws exception: cannot load System.ServiceModel

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

```
<component id="errorhandler1"
           service="System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior, System.ServiceModel"
           type="Nbs.CoreServices.GenericErrorHandler.ErrorHandler, Nbs.CoreServices.GenericErrorHandler" />
```

I am trying to inject a errorhandler component using Castle with WCF. I get this error wherein I get the error , that service is unable to load System.ServiceModel?

Comment: I assume you _did_ add a reference to the System.ServiceModel dll containing WCF, right?

Answer (score 0):

Four possible reasons:

- You do not have a reference to system.serviceModel.dll
- Framework 3.5 (or 3.0) is not installed
- Your project is marked as Framework 2.0
- You are using Visual Studio 2005

Comment: I have checked all of teh above and its 3.5 version.
I am using VS 2008.
System.ServiceModel.dll is in the GAC and even if I put a reference it fails but when I say Copy local = true it seems to work...

Comment: Sounds like you have several versions of System.ServiceModel.dll, try reinstalling Framework 3.5 SP1.

Comment: I agree this is most certainly issue with your code, that has nothing to do with the 3rd party library

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but thought I would weigh in since my company is still kicking it old school with XML component registration over installers.  In our case we used partial assembly name for System.ServiceModel as the O.P. did here.  For whatever reason, this consistently fails.  Oddly, fuslogvw provides a warn instead of an error for this scenario. So moral of story is use fully qualified assembly name for System.ServiceModel when registering WCF components such as IServiceBehavior and IErrorHandler.

Ex:

System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

"Many Bothans died to bring us this information."